# Chrome DevTools: how to permanently highlight an element in the viewport while the cursor is hovering over this DOM element in the Elements tab?

Tags: google-chrome, hover, devtools

In Chrome devtools, when hovering over a DOM element, the size of the element in the viewport is highlighted. Recently, this highlight is not shown all the time, but rather quickly removed.

**How can I make it so that I always see the highlight of an element in the viewport while my cursor is hovering over a DOM element in the Elements tab in DevTools?**

The only thing in the DevTools settings for the Elements tab is "reveal DOM node on hover", but checking or unchecking this checkbox does not affect anything: the behavior is the same: I hover over the DOM node, the size of the element appears in the viewport for a short time, then disappears.

Answer (score -1):

I turned off the React Developer Tools 4.27.1 extension and the backlight stopped disappearing.